# What do I do when "which python" doesn't show a location for python?

Tags: command-line, python

`which python` shows nothing. The following command fixes the issue

```
/usr/bin$ sudo ln -s python3 python
```

But is it a common, safe solution?

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: As I remember `/usr/bin/python` should be linked to python2 and not 3! And use `update-alternatives` to fix these kind of links. I guess installing/reinstalling `python-minimal` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not safe or common at all.

- Historically `python` refers to `python2`, not `python3`
- Many python(2) scripts will break if run using the py3 interpreter
- The reverse is also true: Many py3 scripts will break if run using the py2 interpreter.
- There is no graceful failure - a script run using the wrong interpreter simply spits out a series of cryptic error and quits.

See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for all the details on what the 'python' command should symlink to. Don't stop at the 8-year-old first paragraph, read the entire history section to see how the recommendations have changed over time.

Older releases of Ubuntu (16.04 and older) include both Python2 and Python3 with the default install. Changing `python` on these releases may break your system quite terribly.

Newer releases of Ubuntu (18.04 and newer) include only Python3 with the default install. However, Python2 is trivial to install (`sudo apt install python2`).

Python2 will reach End of Life during 2020, according to [PEP 373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/). However, changing `python` afterward is still not recommended at present.

Comment: Ok, but what is solution of the problem?

Comment: If, in a newly-installed release of Ubuntu 18.04 or newer, the command `which python` returns nothing...that's not a problem. That's an expected behavior. It's *supposed* to return nothing when Python 2 is not installed.

Comment: Hmmm.  While this answer is informative, I don't think it solves the problem.  It just identifies the magnitude of the problem.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Comment: Is it safe to symlink python3 to python on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: No. It's not safe. Don't do it.